# Estou com dificuldades em usar bordas em imagens HTML/css

Tags: html, css, style, padding

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image]
TAVA FAZENDO UNS TESTES EM UMA PÁGINA HIPOTÉTICA, MAS AO TENTAR COLOCAR BORDAS NAS IMAGENS ABAIXO,A PARTIR DA TERCEIRA A BORDA FICA MUITA LARGA. SENDO QUE USEI UMA ÚNICA CLASSE PARA TODAS AS IMAGENS?
ALGUÉM PRA ME AJUDAR?`**código abaixo**

CHampions legue
    


    Top 4 Jogos da Champions league

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você nas 2 primeiras colocou a class principal na tag img já na última colocou na tag a, isso que causa o problema.